# Why NoReverseMatch at occurred on django 2.0

Tags: django, django-urls

Error says :

```
Reverse for 'list' not found. 'list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

My code are on below.

**html template where error is in:**

```
{% block more_posts %}<button type="button" href="{% url 'website:list' %}">more posts</button>{% endblock %}
```

**my_project/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^', include('website.urls')),
]
```

**website/urls.py:**

```
app_name = 'website'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='website/about.html'), name='list'),
    re_path(r'^$', views.main, name='main'),
]
```

Is there are something wrong with my url namespace settings?

Comment: Can you add full tarceback? Looks lke error occured not in the template part you provided.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Thanks but I solved it Would you close this my  question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add namespace

re_path(r'^', include('website.urls',namespcae="website")),